# Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() magento 2

Tags: magento2, installation

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php:500 Stack trace: #0 /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php(34): Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\Mbstring::mb_strpos('/home/hydromark...', '/home/hydromark...', 0, 'UTF-8') #1 /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php(60): mb_strpos('/home/hydromark...', '/home/hydromark...') #2 /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(82): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\PathValidator->validate('/home/hydromark...', '/var/.regenerat...', NULL, false) #3 /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(210): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read->validatePath('/var/.regenerat...') #4 /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/GeneratedFiles.php(66): Magento\Framework\Filesyste in /home/hydromarket/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 500
```

I have try run composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv, but it doesn't work. We are using CENTOS 7.6 xen hvm. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you enable `iconv` extension?

Comment: I have solved it.

Solved: I'm using Cpanel/WHM STACK then follow: Go to WHM >> EasyApache4 >> Current Installed Packages >> customize


Now Select php extensions and search for iconv and debug install both of them and try to install again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it.

Solved: I'm using Cpanel/WHM STACK then follow: Go to WHM >> EasyApache4 >> Current Installed Packages >> customize Now Select php extensions and search for iconv and debug install both of them and try to install again.